# Colour Generator - How to apply colours to all buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner using tutorials to apply stuff on projects.

I'm trying to apply the colours for each of the buttons, but only understand how to apply for the first button. How do I apply colours for all of the buttons and make the colours random?

```js
var numberOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".palette").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
  document
    .querySelectorAll(".palette")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      var n = Math.random();

      n = n * 256;

      n = Math.floor(n);

      var a = Math.random();

      a = a * 256;

      a = Math.floor(a);

      var b = Math.random();

      b = b * 256;

      b = Math.floor(b);

      var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";

      document.getElementById("a").style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use: `querySelectorAll` which an returns an `Array` and then use `forEach` in JS to cycle through all buttons and apply changes to all of them.

Comment: Please ask questions only once.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of it right, but there are a couple of issues and improvements...

Firstly, there is no need to get the items two times (once for the length, the other within the `for` loop)... instead just use the `.forEach`. This is an improvement.

Secondly, there's no need to then specifically get the `id="a"` button when you're already going through all the items. This is more a fix as you're only targetting `id="a"` each time

Try these changes...

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".palette").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var n = Math.random();
    n = n * 256;
    n = Math.floor(n);
    var a = Math.random();
    a = a * 256;
    a = Math.floor(a);
    var b = Math.random();
    b = b * 256;
    b = Math.floor(b);
    var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";
    btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the querySelector in a var so you dont have to query it all the time.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".palette");
var numberOfButtons = buttons.length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var n = Math.random();

    n = n * 256;

    n = Math.floor(n);

    var a = Math.random();

    a = a * 256;

    a = Math.floor(a);

    var b = Math.random();

    b = b * 256;

    b = Math.floor(b);

    var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";

    buttons.forEach(function(button) {
      button.style.backgroundColor = color;
    })
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign `.length` property on the `numberOfButtons`, simply use it everywhere in the code, and use the target element in the function to apply the style.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".palette");

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      var n = Math.random();

      n = n * 256;

      n = Math.floor(n);

      var a = Math.random();

      a = a * 256;

      a = Math.floor(a);

      var b = Math.random();

      b = b * 256;

      b = Math.floor(b);

      var color = "rgb(" + n + "," + a + "," + b + ")";

      e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make function to get random item from array
then make an array consisting different colours like i have made
You can see this code snippet reload the page again and again and you will se  random colours

```js
function getRandomItem(arr) {

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

const item = arr[randomIndex];

return item;
}

    var first_btn = document.getElementById("a");
    var second_btn = document.getElementById("b");
    var third_btn = document.getElementById("c");
    var forth_btn = document.getElementById("d");

    const colors = ["white", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "orange", "pink"];

    var colour = getRandomItem(colors);
    first_btn.style.backgroundColor=colour;
    var colour = getRandomItem(colors);
    second_btn.style.backgroundColor=colour;
    var colour = getRandomItem(colors);
    third_btn.style.backgroundColor=colour;
    var colour = getRandomItem(colors);
    forth_btn.style.backgroundColor=colour;
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
<div class="set">
  <button id="a" class="a palette">a</button>
  <button id="b" class="b palette">b</button>
  <button id="c" class="c palette">c</button>
  <button id="d" class="d palette">d</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<h1 id="title">Color Palette</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button id="a" class="btn palette">a</button>
    <button id="b" class="btn palette">b</button>
    <button id="c" class="btn palette">c</button>
    <button id="d" class="btn palette">d</button>
  </div>


body {
text-align: center;
background-color: black;
}

 .palette {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404b69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #da0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #dbedf3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
 }
```

javascript

```
      const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
      buttonList.forEach(function (btn) {
        const red = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1));
        const green = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1));
        const blue = 0 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1));
        btn.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${red},${green},${blue}`;
      });
```